# How to make HTTPS requests in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, protractor

I already read the sollutions to make http calls inside protractor tests. But the endpoint im consuming is under HTTPS, which causes a Node error: 
`Failed: Protocol "https": not supported. Expected "http:"`

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using `require('http')`? If so, change it to `require('https')`

Comment: @stanpines thanks! worked. You can post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
require('http')
```

to

```
require('https')
```

and it should work!

The reason is because the HTTPS protocol uses special encryption incompatible with Node's HTTP library, and the HTTPS library has the same functions and is compatible.